# Breakpoints debug in Pycharm - multi repository project

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, breakpoints

I'm working on a Python project which includes multiple repositories - it's an automation project. So the main runner triggers different scripts across all the repositories. I've noticed that I can debug (breakpoint) just on one of the repository , which is the one that the main script is called from. 
And if I put a breakpoint in a script that isn't in this repository and not getting to it. 
In Pychram i've defined the in project structure the main folders of each repository as source, thinking it would solve this, but with no success. 
All the folders are sitting under one main "git" folder.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Do I get it right that your main script runs the other projects ("repositories", but let's call them "subprojects") as child processes, not as an in-process Python calls?

If so, you have to:

- attach PyCharm's debugger to those processes by hand, if they run for a noticeable time or can be paused;
- or make your main script only print the subproject invocation arguments, but not run it. Then create a new PyCharm run configuration for the subproject in question by hand, and set its command line arguments the way main script does.